# How to make variable WebDriver's path depending on OS with Serenity BDD?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am working with Serenity BDD and Selenium to automate my project's tests. These tests should be able to be run in both Windows and Ubuntu.

Now, I got the WebDriver's path set in my `serenity.properties` file:

```
#WebDriver for Google Chrome
#-------------------------------
webdriver.driver = chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver = C:\\chromedriver.exe
```

Obviously, webdriver.chrome.driver path only works if project is run in Windows. How can I make variable this path depending on OS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: rename it to `webdriver.windows.chrome.driverlocation` and add another one called `webdriver.linux.chrome.driverlocation`

then, in the startup of your tests you determine the os first and decide which property to work with depending on the os

Comment: @MasterAzazel I did the next trick, but I don't know if it is a good practise. Serenity searches drivers by default in `/usr/bin`(Linux) or `C:\Windows\System32` (Windows). So, if you store the drivers in these folders, there is no need to especify any location.

Comment: great - thats even better!

Comment: @MasterAzazel Can you please tell me how I can determine the property to be used in the startup? Actually I am confused about where to write this code to initialize driver on the basis of OS. I am new to Serenity, and can't find many resources on the configuration of driver path on the basis of OS.

Comment: i suggest you check the documentation. if that doesn't help create a new question with more details